# Tensorflow installation issue version 1.4.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I've installed Tensorflow using the following command:

```
$ pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

The installation looks fine, but when I try to import tensorflow in python I got the following error message:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ep15/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ep15/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ep15/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /home/ep15/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined symbol: cuDevicePrimaryCtxSetFlags
```

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I'm using CUDA 8.0.1

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0
```

If, instead, I follow the instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup

```
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

The installation works, but it's an old version of tf (0.12).

Edit:
It looks like I'm able to install only until version 1.0.0, but I cannot install any later versions.

Comment: Since you were able to install TF, you can just update it using pip: `pip install tensorflow --upgrade`

Comment: It doesn't work, same error.